# non-static method <T>findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, class, findviewbyid

My first app is working fine alone but now I am trying to add tabs following a tutorial but I get stuck.
I've been searching and many users had same issue, I've tried those solutions but still unable to get it working fine.

**My App**

```
package es.ea1ddo.antenacubica;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frecuencia = findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
        cal3el = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular3);
```

And now this is where I am trying to copy the previous app

```
package es.ea1ddo.calculadoraantenascubicas;

public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

        frecuencia = EditText.findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
        cal3el = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.calcular3);
```

I've been searching around, trying many examples and different ways but I am stuck.
You can see I added `getView()`. before every `findViewById` but I am still getting same error:

> non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

Please any advice?
Thanks

Comment: You need to replace `EditText.findViewById` with `(EditText) getView().findViewById`.

Comment: Thanks TheWanderer. Your fix has removed that error. Actually runs free of error but... the app crashes and I can see in the Debug next:  PID: 12271
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference. Targeting same line: frecuencia = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);

Comment: use v.findViewById instead of getView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment code, you have two problems.

The first, as others have pointed out, is that `View.findViewById()` is a non-static method, so you would invoke it like `myView.findViewById()` as opposed to `EditText.findViewById()`.

The second relates to how the Fragment's `getView()` method works. This method only works **after** `onCreateView()` has returned, because `getView()` returns whatever `onCreateView()` returned. That means that you can't call `getView()` from within `onCreateView()`; it will always return `null`.

Put together, your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

    frecuencia = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
    cal3el = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calcular3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ben, you are the man. It is working now !! By the way, all the (EditText) and the (Button) are greyed showing "Casting ... is redundant" so i removed and still works fine. The only greyed thing is "inflater" in this line: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,... showing "Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter". Is that ok?

Comment: Yeah that's fine. It's telling you that you're overriding a method that was defined with `@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater` but you've only typed `LayoutInflater inflater`. You could add the annotation if you want or you can just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
frecuencia = EditText.findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
cal3el = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.calcular3);
```

with

```
recuencia = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
cal3el = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calcular3);
```

if not work please add full xml code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
EditText.findViewById
```

with

```
(ExitText) getView().findViewById
```

However, this will result in a NullPointerException.

You need to move any code that uses `getView()` into `onViewCreated()`, or reference `v` instead.